# Counting the number of words beginning with a CAPITAL VOWEL using a Recursive function

Tags: java

This is my code below which counts and displays the number of words beginning with a capital vowel:
The function count() is a recursive function which counts the number of such words.

```
import java.util.*;

class Check
{
    String str; int w; 

    StringTokenizer S; 
    void InputString()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String:");
        str=sc.nextLine();
    }

    void counter(int nWord)
    {                     
        if(nWord<=S.countTokens())
        {
            String word=S.nextToken(); 
            char first=word.charAt(0); 
            if(first=='A' || first=='E' || first=='I' || first=='O' || first=='U')
            //Checking if the word begins with a CAPITAL VOWEL.
            {
                w++; 
            }
            counter(nWord+1);
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        S=new StringTokenizer(str);
        counter(1);
        System.out.println("Given String: "+str);
        System.out.println("Number of words beginning with capital vowels = "+w);
    }

    void main()
    {
        InputString();
        display();
    }
}
```

For input: "Java Is An Object Oriented Programming Language."
 Output: number of such words=3

But clearly, there are 4 such words in the given String. I would like to know where I made a mistake.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc says about `StringTokenizer.countTokens()`:

> Calculates the number of times that this tokenizer's nextToken method
>   can be called before it generates an exception. The current position
>   is not advanced.

In other words, after each call of `nextToken`, `countTokens` will return a lower number.
This causes your `counter` to be called not as often as you expect.

Instead of `if (nWord<=S.countTokens())`, try `if (S.countTokens() > 0)`.

Comment: I see..I did not know that. It works as expected now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because S.countTokens() return **remaining number of tokens** in the tokenizer. Initially, there are 7 tokens in "*Java Is An Object Oriented Programming Language*". When you call `S.nextToken()`, it **removes** "Java" from the list and upon next call of `S.countTokens()`, we get 6 (instead of 7, since Java is no more in the list of tokens).

The loop ends when you have read 4 tokens, and there are only 3 more tokens left. At this stage, `nWord = 4` but `S.countTokens() = 3`, **so the recursion stops here** and you don't get to the words "Oriented Programming Language" at all.

To fix this, count the number of tokens initially in display() function itself and store it in a variable nTokens. Then the checking condition becomes:

```
if(nWord <= nTokens)
```

The full code would then look like:

```
import java.util.*;

class Check
{
    String str; int w;
    int nTokens; //this variable stores number of tokens 

    StringTokenizer S; 
    void InputString()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String:");
        str=sc.nextLine();
    }

    void counter(int nWord)
    {                     
        if(nWord<=nTokens) //the changed condition
        {
            String word=S.nextToken(); 
            char first=word.charAt(0); 
            if(first=='A' || first=='E' || first=='I' || first=='O' || first=='U')
            //Checking if the word begins with a CAPITAL VOWEL.
            {
                w++; 
            }
            counter(nWord+1);
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        S=new StringTokenizer(str);
        nTokens = S.countTokens();

        counter(1);
        System.out.println("Given String: "+str);
        System.out.println("Number of words beginning with capital vowels = "+w);
    }

    void main()
    {
        InputString();
        display();
    }
}
```

This code correctly outputs 4 as expected.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The class does not evaluate all the words of the input, that is why the number is off.

When you print out the parameter `nWord` and the return value of `S.countTokens()` in `count()`, you will see that while `nWord` increases, the return value of `countTokens()` *decreases* with each call until it is smaller than `nWord`, which will stop the recursion before all the tokens are looked at.

The countTokens() function returns the number of *remaining* tokens, not the *total* number of tokens, so it decreases while the tokens are consumed by `nextToken()`.

```
Enter a String:
Java Is An Object Oriented Programming Language.
nWord=1 countTokens=7
Java
nWord=2 countTokens=6
Is
nWord=3 countTokens=5
An
nWord=4 countTokens=4
Object
nWord=5 countTokens=3
Given String: Java Is An Object Oriented Programming Language.
Number of words beginning with capital vowels = 3
```

You could just use the preferred function `hasMoreTokens()` of the `StringTokenizer` to see if there are more tokens to process and then the result will be correct:

```
...
if(S.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String word=S.nextToken();
...

Enter a String:
Java Is An Object Oriented Programming Language.
Given String: Java Is An Object Oriented Programming Language.
Number of words beginning with capital vowels = 4
```